# How to access regex groups using For Each Controller in JMeter

Tags: regex, variables, scripting, automation, jmeter

is it possible to access different groups using output variable of `ForEach controller`?

For instance I'm using `Regular Expression Extractor` which extracts 2 elements and both of them have 2 groups.

Using `Debug Sampler` I'm seeing that values are extracted correctly:

```
treenodes_1_g1=id1
treenodes_1_g2=First title
treenodes_2_g1=id2
treenodes_2_g2=Second title
```

Next I'm iterating results using `ForEach Controller` with:

```
input variable: treenodes
output variable name: node
Add "_" before number: checked
```

And I would like to use something `${node_${C}_g2}` for titles in Name field in `View Results Tree` and `${node_${C}_g1}` in some other place, where ${C} is counter variable according to http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller.

Values are not resolved properly so for instance I see `${node_${C}_g2}` as a `${node_${C}_g2}` text instead of `First title`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate multiple variables you need to use the __V function.

[JMeter _V() Function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

```
${__V(node_${C})}

${__V(node_${C}_g2)}
```